# How to insert nested lists (or nested block elements) into RichTextBlock?

Tags: html, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, markdown, richtextblock

Global task: display Markdown text in Windows Store App. 
How I think to do it: Markdown -> HTML -> XAML RichTextBlock

More specific purpose: display nested lists like this:

1. item 1
2. item 2

   - subitem 1
   - subitem 2 + img-tag + test text + blockquote + code (multiline item)

More global purpose: render nested block-elements.

Problem: it seems, that it is possible to insert into RichTextBlock only block elements (and there is only one element - Paragraph), and into Paragraph - only inline elements.

Current solution is such nesting: `RichTextBlock > Paragraph > InlineUIContainer > RichTextBlock ...`. But it feels like a bad idea.

Any idea how to do it right?

Answer (score 1):

Ok Ill start with silverlight.

There was a TreeView Control in silverlight that would have exactly solved your problem.

[Link to tree view example](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/treeview.aspx)

But since we already know that winRt is a subset of API's these controls have been removed for metro app. More over microsofts design policy regarding the Type Of scenario you are mentioning has changed to :

[Semantic Zoom For Metro Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465319.aspx)

So i advise if your app requirement is like that Either go with the richtextbox or use Grids with Rows and columns Which ever suits your coding best.

One more way is to use third party library for tree structure .

[Syncfusion tree control](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/controls)

Syncfusion has a tree control you can try out in the Demo. Even there are more third party tool but none are free not even he above one.
 Please Let me know if any more concerns.